# How to calculate the total resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

So I am new to physics and I am trying to solve the total resistance of this circuit. My question is: because there is a battery in the same branch as R2 and a Capacitor in the same branch as R3, when calculating the Total resistance all the resistance should be R1//R2//R3, because there is no way to simplify the resistors?

[image]

Comment: Where would you place the "total resistance" in the circuit?

Comment: The "total resistance" of a circuit is meaningless. Do you perhaps want to calculate the current?

Comment: No, I want to calculate the time constant using R * C, for that I need the total resistance.
And I think there is not a way to place the "total resistance" without really changing the circuit

Comment: The usual way to say this is that you want the "dynamic resistance" of part of the circuit, in this case the part without the capacitor.

Comment: So one must assume that the capacitor is not there to calculate the dynamic resistance? How is that done?

Comment: You assume the capacitor isn't there by leaving it out. To find the resistance of the rest of the circuit, put an ohmmeter in its place, except that doesn't work because the batteries don't obey Ohm's law. Your textbook should have examples of how to solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not since this is from an exam without solutions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thévenin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) can be applied here. Essentially, in the equivalent circuit for calculation of time constant, short-circuit the EMF sources and treat the two ends of the capacitor as the entry and exit point of current. In your case:

[image: RC]

Now calculate the equivalent resistance between A and B.